# Loop Logic of an array , unique id

Tags: php, logic, analysis

I hope someone give an idea how I do this.

I have this data:

```
0 -> id=1 other_id = 2
1 -> id=1 other_id = 3
2 -> id=1 other_id = 4
3 -> id=2 other_id = 7
4 -> id=2 other_id = 5
```

Now, in my loop, I'd like to push unique ids and concatenate the other id data so the result will be:

```
0-> id=1 other_ids = 2,3,4
1-> id=2 other_ids = 7,5
```

I'm thinking of using temporary variable but can't do data structure.

By the way I'm using codeigniter, result is from model and I'd like to manipulate it in the controller via php.

Answer (score 0):

i hope help you

step 1 : Create Class

```
public class Person
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int other_id { get; set; }
    }
```

Step 1 : this code will help you

```
string output = string.Empty;

        List<Person> lst = new List<Person>();
        lst.Add(new Person(){ id= 1, other_id = 2});
        lst.Add(new Person(){ id= 1, other_id = 3});
        lst.Add(new Person(){ id= 1, other_id = 4});
        lst.Add(new Person(){ id= 2, other_id = 7});
        lst.Add(new Person(){ id= 2, other_id =5 });

        List<int> idlst = new List<int>();
        idlst = lst.Select(x => x.id).Distinct().ToList();


        foreach (int _id in idlst) 
        {
            List<int> other_idlist = lst.Where(x => x.id == _id).Select(x=> x.other_id).ToList();
            output += string.Format("id={0} other_ids = {1}", _id, string.Join(",", other_idlist)) + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(output);
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I missed tagging my question for php. I'm checking on your code given and I'll see if i can convert this to php.